# Information consoles/alerts correctly, won't output into html though

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using `.each()` to get a set of lis. After getting the group(li) data, subtract it from the current year and then console the amount. I then want to pass that to a if statement, if it is equal to or less than 2 print a star for each one.

Right now it consoles and alerts correctly but when I try to use `.html("*")`to print the star, it only prints one.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ycxLez2y/4/).

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li data-year="2012">One</li>
    <li data-year="1984">Two</li>
    <li data-year="2009">Three</li>
    <li data-year="2014">Four</li>
    <li data-year="2014">Five</li>
    <li data-year="2014">Six</li>
    <li data-year="2003">Seven</li>
    <li data-year="2002">Eight</li>
    <li data-year="2014">Nine</li>
    <li data-year="2014">Ten</li>
</ul>

<div id="stars"></div>
```

**Javascript / Jquery**

```
var mem = $("li");
var year = new Date().getFullYear();

mem.each(function() {
    var stay = $(this).data('year');
    var amount = year - stay;
    console.log(amount);

    if(amount <= 2) {
        console.log("I am less than or equal to two: " + amount);
        $('#stars').html("*");
    }
});
```

Comment: You need append the html, when you use html("XYZ") replace the html content. e.g you can $("#starts").html($("#starts").html() + "*");

Comment: It gets overwritten, so your output will always be one star.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$('#stars').html('*');` with `$('#stars')[0].innerHTML += '*';`

That will append the string to the innerHTML of the DOM element that your selector selected

Answer (score 1):

That's because `.html()` overwrites the existing HTML - create a variable, append the `*` to it, then add that:

```
var stars = "";
mem.each(function() {
    var stay = $(this).data('year');
    var amount = year - stay;
    console.log(amount);

    if(amount <= 2) {
        console.log("I am less than or equal to two: " + amount);
        stars += "*"
    }
});

$('#stars').html(stars);
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call

`$('#stars').html("*");`

you're effectively replacing the text between the star's opening/closing tags.

You may want to to do this:

```
var currentHTML = $('#stars').html();
$('#stars').html(currentHTML + "*");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var mem = $("li");
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
var stars ="";
mem.each(function() {
    var stay = $(this).data('year');
    var amount = year - stay;
    console.log(amount);
    if(amount <= 2) {
        //console.log("I am less than or equal to two: " + amount);
        stars ="*"+stars;
    }
});
$('#stars').append(stars);
```

Use append to add to the previous content

Comment: Won't this double the amount of stars each time?

Comment: actually even the previous answer was correc.. Reason:  I was anyway setting stars variable each time to "" :)